# Accessing properties file in aar file

Tags: web-services, properties, apache-axis

I have create a property file and am accessing this property file through my code as:

```
java.util.Properties clientProperties = new java.util.Properties();
        try{
            System.out.println("reading properties file");
            clientProperties.load(new FileInputStream("Get_Remove.properties"));
            String CONF_FILE_EHCACHE_XML = clientProperties.get("CONF_FILE_EHCACHE_XML").toString();
            System.out.println("ehcache_Address : " + CONF_FILE_EHCACHE_XML);
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Property file read exception: ");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now i have deployed my project containing the above code as AAR file in axis2. But when i start the axis2 server and hit the above service then when reading property file, it throws exception at axis2 console as:

```
Property file read exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Get_Remove.properties (The system cannot f
ind the path specified)
```

So how can i access my .property file from my service deployed in axis2 as .aar file.
Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing files from a Java code, you have to think about the path. There are many ways to get the path for your file.

I guess your property file is at the root of your AAR file.

Please try following code:

`clientProperties.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Get_Remove.properties"));`

I hope this helps.

Thanks!